# EOF error when I try to use 'expect' function from'Pexpect'

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm trying to automate the process of switch between networks in "Cisco AnyConnect", but my code always is terminated with an 'EOF error'.

I've tried a search in API doc for some help and used different expressions like: "Network", "Network:" or "Network.*".

```py
from pexpect import popen_spawn
import pexpect

vpnui = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe', maxread=2000)
vpnui.expect('Network:')
vpnui.sendline('SomeNetwork')
```

[image: An Image reference]

**The error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py",
>   line 111, in expect_loop
>       incoming = spawn.read_nonblocking(spawn.maxread, timeout)   File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\popen_spawn.py",
>   line 75, in read_nonblocking
>       raise EOF('End Of File (EOF).') pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF).
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\myUser\eclipse-workspace\teste\switchGuestWifi.py", line 15,
>   in 
>       vpnui.expect('Network:')   File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py",
>   line 341, in expect
>       timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)   File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py",
>   line 369, in expect_list
>       return exp.expect_loop(timeout)   File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py",
>   line 117, in expect_loop
>       return self.eof(e)   File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py",
>   line 63, in eof
>       raise EOF(msg) pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF). 
>   searcher: searcher_re:
>       0: re.compile(b'Network:')

Comment: `Expect` is for automating programs that run in the terminal, not GUI applications.

Comment: But are there any other method that I can use or another way that I can do it? I've tried a search in API doc but don't found anything.

Comment: You need to check the documentation of the Cisco application to find out if it provides any automation method.